# Look up in dictionary

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dictionary, keybindings

Is there a way to bind the chrome style look up in dictionary to a key binding? In case you don't know what function I'm talking about here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The default keyboard shortcut for Define is⇧⌘D. This isn't a Google Chrome feature—rather, it's an OS X and iOS feature using Dictionary.app.